# Add cookie function to color changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies, background-color

I have made a colorchanger via jQuery, but was unable to make a cookie function so the color preference would be remembered.
Here is the code;

```
<body> 
<button id="grey">Grey</button>
<button id="red">Red</button>
<button id="pink">Pink</button>
<button id="blue">Blue</button>
<button id="green">Green</button>
<button id="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button id="orange">Orange</button> 
</body>
```

Here is jQuery Used :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("button#grey").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","#111") }) 
 $("button#red").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","red") }) 
 $("button#pink").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","pink") }) 
 $("button#blue").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","blue") }) 
 $("button#green").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","green") }) 
 $("button#yellow").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","yellow") }) 
 $("button#orange").click(function(){ $("body").css("background","orange") }) });
```

Here is the fiddle : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/envira/HfG5t/)

Help is appreciated :)
Thank you

Comment: There is no code there that shows how you tried to set / get a cookie. What have you tried?

Comment: I posted the plain code used for the plugin, not the faulty cookie code which doesnt work. I would be grateful if you have provided a solutio> if you want the code i used with cookies you could navigate to here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/envira/CuS9B/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple jquery plugin that helps with setting/getting cookie values.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You could use it like so:

```
$("button#grey").click(function() {
   $("body").css("background", "#111")
   $.cookie("bg-color", "#111")
}
```

and then when your page loads

```
$(document).read(function() {
  $("body").css("background", $.cookie("bg-color"));
});
```

Make sure to first check if the bg-color value has been set!

Comment: By the way... if you want to learn how $.cookie sets/gets cookie values, you should take a look at the code on github.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though, i have tried adding the cookie but the code seems not to work , any help [link](http://jsfiddle.net/envira/CuS9B/1/)

Comment: You're missing parens after the last curly brace in each of your onclick statements.

Comment: oops, thanks for the tip, but i cant get the cookie function to work. Here is latest fiddle. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/envira/CuS9B/3/). I am new to jQuery cookie usage. Thanks for help, regards

Comment: Your fiddle links works for me... If I choose a color and then refresh the page, the background is that color.

Comment: Hello, Thanks, yes its working in the fiddle, but when i port the same into a HTML file it is not working. The cookie plugin is included. , Thanks for help. regards